# Is there an automatic translator from Makefile to CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: make, cmake, gnu-make

I have several inherited projects - on RHEL 7, part of which are created using `make,` and the rest are utilising `cmake.`

I'm wondering: is there an *automatic translator* that will take a `Makefile` as input, and will generate a *basis* for a `CMakeLists.txt,` which I will then tweak manually?

*Note:* Google returns quite a few results for `cmake generators,` but seems that these don't do what I describe above. Same goes for `cmake converters` and `cmake translators.`